# showing that a space being contractible is not the same as having a deformation retracting to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show that for a space X being contractible is not the same as having a deformation retracting to a point.
I understand the difference since in the "Retraction" the point doesn't move ,but how can I prove it ?

Comment: find an example....

Comment: This was asked on this site before. Use the search feature. The exercises in chapter 0 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology provide a couple of examples.